# User.Groups is empty when trying to enumerate in SharePoint CSOM C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to get a user by its id in SharePoint 2013 via CSOM C#:

```
        clientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        User gUser = web.GetUserById(selectedUserId);
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.Load(gUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Group gGroup in gUser.Groups)
                {
                    ...
                }
```

But i get always the following error message:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

What i want to do is:

- get the user from sharepoint by its user id
- loop through user.groups
  (get users groups)

I am googling around since this morning, but cannot find any solution/description how to solve this.

Comment: what is clientContext?

Comment: `clientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);` question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to EF eager vs lazy loading issue. In SP, only simple properties of objects are loaded by default (string, date, number, boolean). Other properties will need to be explicitly loaded. To do that, you need to do this:

```
clientContext.Load(gUser.Groups);
```

That will load the `Groups` collection as well. Now you can access it.